# ld cannot find existing library

Tags: symlink, ld

I'm trying to build a large application, yet for some reason linking fails and ld responds

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so

Steps I've tried:

1. libx11-dev is correctly installed and the file libX11.so is a symlink that points to libX11.so.6.3.0
2. Removed the link and recreated it with `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so`
3. `ldconfig -v` to update the cache. No luck...

Anybody have any idea?

**UPDATE**

Sato Katsura posted a very helpful comment, suggesting I use `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lX11` instead. This did work, and the application compiled without further issue!

Could anyone enlighten me as to what the difference is?

Comment: Try `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lX11` instead of `-l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so`.

Comment: `-labc` (lower ell) searches, in possibly multiple directories depending your platform, for a file named `libabc.x` where x is either `a` for static or a platform-dependent suffix _sometimes_ `so` for dynamic. You only specify abc; you don't specify the directory, or `lib`, or `.so`.